# Is it possible to edit read only page(same page)?

Tags: visualforce, redirect

I have created visual force page it's read only page. when I click the button called modify(find below images) it's redirect to same page with editable. Is it possible to create? can you please tell me how can I do this? Please find the attached images.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code why which you made it disabled?

Comment: @Ashwani  thanks for your response. I am not able to post my whole code.<apex:pageblock title="Period 1" id="blockA">
  
    <apex:outputLabel ><b>Upper Date</b></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!Period1Date}" disabled="true" >
     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="--None--" itemvalue=""></apex:selectOption>
     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="1" itemvalue="1"></apex:selectOption>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example how you can do this. As you can see you have to use condition `disabled="{!enabled}"` to disable/enable the fields. On button click you have to rerender the form with all fields enabled. Hope this will help.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form id="theform"> 
         <apex:inputText value="{!blah}" disabled="{!enabled}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="modify" action="{!modify}" rerender="theform"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public Class MyController {
    public boolean enabled {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String blah {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public MyController() {
        enabled = true;
    }
    public void modify() {
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```